# Chrome API feature to block rendering until all changes applied

Tags: performance, google-chrome, dom, rendering

I know there is API in Chrome which gives the option to prevent changes rendering and layout changes until you add all your changes and "release" the block so it will calculate layout and rendering only once and not for each change I do in the DOM.

anyone knows what is this API?

Answer (score 0):

This is called a '[Virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html).' The most popular one is part of [react.js](https://reactjs.org/).

Comment: no. there is new API in Chrome for it. not 3rd party library. from chrome 70 or something.